# the selected document class requires external files that are not available - LyX portable

Tags: lyx, theorems, article, portability

I'm using LyX portable on windows, and I get this message

> the selected document class article(hebrew) requires external files
>   that are not avialable. ... the following prerequisites are installed:
>   article.cls theorem.sty

I can't convert lyx to pdf. i have seen an answer to this question, but not for LyX portable.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I write my [thesis](https://github.com/rwmpelstilzchen/thesis) in Hebrew using XeLaTeX and the [`bidi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package (היי, נעים להכיר ☺), and if it is possible for you to use XeLaTeX+`bidi`, I recommend it wholeheartedly. Everything works so much smoother, easier and with a greater flexibility in comparison to (pdf)LaTeX.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Ubuntu or any linux distro try to do these:

1. Search for texlive-latex-extra AND tex-math-extra AND texlive-lang-hebrew in any package manager and install them
2. In LyX press Tools>Reconfigure
3. Restart LyX

Comment: If Fedora or another RPMy distribution, `yum install 'tex(missing.sty)'` gets the missing piece(s) and dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the job!

Comment: Note that it is not tex-math-extra but texlive-math-extra